# How do I score a questionnaire and visualize a total score?

Tags: r, shiny, data-visualization

I'm new to RShiny, so please pardon my ignorance.

I have a questionnaire that I am trying to score. I would like to create a visual of the total score like what is shown below [image: Total Score Example])

As you'll see in the full example below, I am computing the total score as

```
  Y <<- responses %>%
    mutate_all(funs(recode(., 'Not at all' = 0, 'Several days' = 1, 'More than half the days' = 2, 'Nearly every day' = 3)))
  
  score <<-(apply(Y, 1, sum))
```

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
rm(list = ls())
require(shiny)
require(tidyverse)

#setwd('C:/Users/Ethan.Arenson/OneDrive - OneWorkplace/Documents/Methodology/Conference Presentations/DataViz/R')
setwd('C:/Users/Ethan.Arenson/OneDrive - OneWorkplace/Documents/Projects/NO8027E/App/App')

fieldsAll <- c("nervous", "stop.worry", "worry", "relax", "restless", "annoyed", "afraid")

# resp.options <- c('Not at all' = 0, 'Several days' = 1, 'More than half the days' = 2, 'Nearly every day' = 3)
resp.options <- c('Not at all', 'Several days', 'More than half the days', 'Nearly every day')

saveData <- function(data) 
{
  data <- as.data.frame(t(data))
  if (exists("responses")) 
  {
    responses <<- rbind(data)
  } else {
    responses <<- data
  }
  # n.items <<- 10
  

  Y <<- responses %>%
    mutate_all(funs(recode(., 'Not at all' = 0, 'Several days' = 1, 'More than half the days' = 2, 'Nearly every day' = 3)))
  
  score <<-(apply(Y, 1, sum))
  

  names(responses) <<- c('Feeling nervous/on edge',
                        'Not being able to stop worrying',
                        'Worrying about differnt things',
                        'Trouble relaxing',
                        'Being restless',
                        'Becoming easily annoyed',
                        'Feeling afraid')
  
  
}



loadData <- function() {
  if (exists("responses")) {
    responses
  }
}

loadScore <- function() {
  if (exists("score")) {
    score
  }
}

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    titlePanel("The Generalized Anxiety Disorder 7-Item (GAD-7) Scale"),
    fluidRow(
      column(6,
             selectInput("nervous", "Over the last 2 weeks, how much have you been bothered by feeling nervous or on edge?", 
                         resp.options),
             selectInput("stop.worry", "Over the last 2 weeks, how much have you been bothered by not being able to stop or control worrying?", 
                         resp.options),
             selectInput("worry", "Over the last 2 weeks, how much have you been bothered by worrying too much about different things?", 
                         resp.options),
             selectInput("relax", "Over the last 2 weeks, how much have you been bothered by trouble relaxing?", 
                         resp.options)),
      column(6,
             selectInput("restless", "Over the last 2 weeks, how much have you been bothered by being so restless that it's hard to sit still?", 
                         resp.options),
             selectInput("annoyed", "Over the last 2 weeks, how much have you been bothered by becoming easily annoyed or irritable?", 
                         resp.options),
             selectInput("afraid", "Over the last 2 weeks, how much have you been bothered by feeling afraid as if something awful might happen?", 
                         resp.options),
             plotOutput("plot", height = 300)
      ),
    ),
    fluidRow(
      actionButton("submit", "Submit")
    ),
    
    fluidRow(
      DT::dataTableOutput("responses", width = 200), 
      tags$hr(),
       ),
       fluidRow(
         textOutput("score")
        )
    
    
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    
    # Whenever a field is filled, aggregate all form data
    formData <- reactive({
      data <- sapply(fieldsAll, function(x) input[[x]])
      data
    })
    
    # When the Submit button is clicked, save the form data
    observeEvent(input$submit, {
      saveData(formData())
      
    })
    
    # Show the previous responses
    # (update with current response when Submit is clicked)
    output$responses <- DT::renderDataTable({
      
      input$submit
      loadData()
    },
    options=list(dom = 't',
                 ordering = FALSE)
    )
    
    output$score <- renderText({
      input$submit
      paste("Your score is", loadScore())
    })

})
      }
  

  )
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, I'm not sure where you want this scale diagram or what you want the labels to be. What I added here won't render when you source. You will have to either let me know the rest or if you can take it from here...

You had a comment about n.items = 10, but there are seven questions now, so I made it dynamic, based on the length of what you send to the function `saveData()`.

This keeps the gradient uniform, regardless of the score. However, I added comments on how to change it if you wanted the gradient to change based on their score.

This looks like a lot, but it is mostly comments.

The only changes I made were in the function `saveData()`:

```
saveData <- function(data) 
{
  data <- as.data.frame(t(data))
  if (exists("responses")) 
  {
    responses <<- rbind(data)
  } else {
    responses <<- data
  }
  # n.items <<- 10
  
  Y <<- responses %>%
    mutate_all(funs(recode(., 'Not at all' = 0, 'Several days' = 1, 
                           'More than half the days' = 2, 
                           'Nearly every day' = 3)))
  
  score <<-(apply(Y, 1, sum))
  
  
  names(responses) <<- c('Feeling nervous/on edge',
                         'Not being able to stop worrying',
                         'Worrying about differnt things',
                         'Trouble relaxing',
                         'Being restless',
                         'Becoming easily annoyed',
                         'Feeling afraid')
  # code above is from your posted question, below is from me
  
  # find max score 
  lenData = length(data) * 3     # you have the largest value question = 3
  
  # create a data frame to store info for the gradient
  fillData = data.frame(stX = seq(from = 0, to = lenData, length.out = 1000))
  fillData$enX <- fillData$stX
  
  # this will be the denominator in the slope calculation (gradient)
  sDenom <- lenData/2                 # gradient that is static
  # sDenom <- lenData - score * 1000  # change point in gradient based on score
  
  # to get the slope where y is 1/10 the width of x or lenData/10
  # the slope is the midpoint of y divided by the midpoint of x
  fillSlope <- (lenData/10/2)/sDenom
        
  # add the start for the fill
  fillData$stY <- rep(x = 0, times = nrow(fillData))
  
  # the end values of y for the gradient depend on which gradient you want to use
  # static or dynamic based on the score
  fillData <- mutate(fillData, 
                     enY = ifelse(stX <= (sDenom + lenData),
                                  yes = lenData/10,   # max y
                                  no = lenData/10/2 + stX - (sDenom + lenData) * sDenom))
                                     # calculate y using the mx + b slope formula
                                     # intercept is lenData/10/2; midpoint y
  p <- ggplot(data = fillData) + 
    geom_segment(aes(x = stX,
                     xend = enX,
                     y = stY,
                     yend = enY,
                     color = stX)) +
    # if you want the green to red rainbow this works:
    scale_color_distiller(palette = "RdYlGn",  # from package R Color Brewer
                          guide = "none") +    # no legend
    coord_fixed() +                            # keep the aspect ratio
    geom_vline(xintercept = score,
               size = 2, color = "black") +    # mark the score
    theme_void()                               # pretend it is not a graph
  
}
```

I used `theme_void()`, but you have many options, depending on what you wanted it to look like.

I put some values in for the object `data`. This is what this code will produce when you figure out where you want it. The vertical line is the score based on the values I used.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Kat, for the help.

But, I'm not able to produce the gradient. Do I need to have some type of 

```
output$plot <- renderPlot({ ... })
```
statement?

Comment: @EthanArenson That is probably because you don't have the package `RColorBrewer` installed. You don't have to call the library, but you do need the package. Let me know if that doesn't work!